# How do I make a function tick atomically if the document is not modified after a certain period of time

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, backend, mern

Hello I am working with mongoose/mongodb and have this data structure

```
{
   step: "Lorem",
   status: "in-progress",
   bool: true,
   startedAt: Date.now(),
   inactive: false
}
```

how do I make it so if there are no changes to the first three attibutes after a certain period of time `inactive` is set to true

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CRON, here is some pseudo code

```
//query
{$lte: updatedAt: today, subtracted by 2months}
//update
{$set: attr to 'whatever you want'}
//db call
db.collection.updateMany(query, update)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra field `updateAt`, everytime `step` or `status` or `bool` changed, you also need to change `updateAt`.

Finally you can check `updateAt`.

```
{
   step: "Lorem",
   status: "in-progress",
   bool: true,
   startedAt: Date.now(),
   updateAt: Date.now(),
   inactive: false
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that; however, I do not want to check updatedAt manually I want the server to do it automatically, through mongodb and was asking if that was possible